# What kind of switch takes a 12v in sends it to one of two output wires?

Tags: switches

I'm looking for a switch that I can use in my car.

A sensor sends a 12v signal through a wire, into a switch, and out via one of two wires.

For example, if the switch is set to position 1, the 12v will exit through wire 1. Switch position 2, exit via wire 2.

Here's a rough diagram, and my apologies for any incorrect terminology (first time doing anything electrical).
[image: Diagram of the layout]

Comment: This is a [SPDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) switch.

Comment: Don't answer in the comments.

Comment: note that most automotive switches are spst with a light section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do Google Images "SPDT" you'll get a huge list of circuit diagrams and photographs that might help clarify things.  Not really a lot else to say.  They're named like this:-

[image: switches]

Apart from one thing.  Make sure that the current rating of the switch (and wires) is adequate.  Don't use a little logic level switch to change between the main battery and the additional battery for the 2T winch.  Any concerns, ask here...

Comment: Bought a SPDT 12v 24A 3 pin, it's just to intercept a clutch pedal switch and route it to either the main harness ECU port, or a launch control options port.